# PHP: How to sending the POST data using Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: php, windows, post, scheduled-tasks

I would like to implement an automation PHP script to read my data every 5 minutes in Windows server and then any newly edited data has to be transmit to another PHP script to read and save to the database.

1. Server A (Windows server) has database A (MSSQL) and PHP A.
2. Server B (Windows server) has database B (MySQL) and PHP B.
3. PHP A reads database A every 5 minutes, only new / edited data to be read.
4. **PHP A (IP_address_1/URL_1) sending data to PHP B (IP_address_2/URL_2).**
5. PHP B reads data and dump them into database B

I need to work out the part 4, which I do not know how to set a task scheduler to open the file and then send the data to another PHP script to read and save into database that located in another server.

Problems:

1. How to send data in PHP file automatically? By POST data, and how? Or any other method to sending / transmitting data automatically to another server's PHP file?
2. How to set task scheduler in Windows server to open this PHP file. I do not want to learn build-in CRON job. But something similar way.

In my PHP B, I need to read the POST data from PHP A, this is the main part.
So, how to let my **PHP A sending the POST data** without someone click the submit button, and it is **using task scheduler** to submit.

Comment: And there is no way to connect PHP A with Database B?

Answer (score 0):

To POST data, you need to use cURL. You can learn more at:

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Sample code:

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init("www.example.com/curl.php?option=test");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);       
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $output;
?>
```